# preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Tags: php, html, function, codeigniter, preg-match

i use this code

```
<div class="title" style="background: url(./content/images/green/<?=preg_match('1|3|5|7',$sekolah['ijenis_sekolah'])?'j_header_left.png':'j_header_left_2.png'?>) no-repeat; height: 90px;">
```

and i found an error like this

> Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

what should i do?

Comment: `preg_match('/1|3|5|7/', ...`?

Comment: preg_match is considering | as delimiter, instead of using | try to use [1357] instead, like it can be 1 3 5 or 7

Comment: @Sirius preg_match is considering `1` and `7` as delimiter.

Comment: yes @bansi i made a mistake